# kcfinder image upload popup shows with direct php content

Tags: php, image, yii, upload, kcfinder

I used the kcfinder in my Yii site

while clicking the image upload button it opens the following popup.

[image: click here to view the popup.]

Here, while clicking 'Browse server' button, the popup opened, but it shows the php code.
The url passed is::
http://sitename.com/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files&CKEditor=BbiiMessage_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en

It displays the direct php content instead of image upload screen

```
            <?php

        /** This file is part of KCFinder project
          *
          *      @desc Browser calling script
          *   @package KCFinder
          *   @version 3.10
          *    @author Pavel Tzonkov <sunhater@sunhater.com>
          * @copyright 2010-2014 KCFinder Project
          *   @license http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0 GPLv3
          *   @license http://opensource.org/licenses/LGPL-3.0 LGPLv3
          *      @link http://kcfinder.sunhater.com
          */

        require "core/bootstrap.php";
        $browser = "kcfinder\\browser"; // To execute core/bootstrap.php on older
        $browser = new $browser();      // PHP versions (even PHP 4)
        $browser->action();

        ?>
```

I don't know why. Its working fine in my local wamp server. please help me.

Answer (score 4):

i have this problem too.
delete .htaccess file in KCFinder Folder

Answer (score 0):

Probably in was happening if PHP not installed on your server or not configured in virtual host.

Comment: `I used the kcfinder in my Yii site` I guess OP would have noticed it long before, since he's using a PHP framework